# Django render not working when redirected from another view

Tags: python, django, redirect, model-view-controller, django-views

I have two views as follows

```
def home(request):
    levels = levelData.objects.all()
    context ={
            "levels" : levels
    }
    print "abcde"
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

and the other one

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # doing something with data with saveData as variable of model type
        saveData.save()
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'create.html')
```

Now, inside the create view, I wish to redirect to home view after saving data. Redirect is working fine and it's being redirected to home as the print statement in home view is executed and "abcde" is printed in terminal. But, home.html does not get rendered and it remains on create.html. Also, the url doesn't change.

This is home view in my urls.py

```
url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you posting your data via ajax?(js/jquery/or something likethat)

Comment: yes via ajax from js

Comment: Thankyou for the comment. I could guess the problem and googled it and apparently adding `top.location.href = "/";` served the purpose. I couldn't understand the reason for this. It'd be great if you could respond with the reason for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are posting through `AJAX`, you cannot do that.You have to do like

```
window.location.href = '/redirecturl/'
```

in AJAX `success` callback.

Comment: because that sets the href location... thats how ajax works ... there are many many many tutorials about the difference between client side and server side actions...